# Calculate proportion from duplicate values

Tags: excel

Maybe I am searching incorrectly, but can't find an answer for something I hope is fairly simple in Excel.

I have a sheet which is something like:

```
Hospital A   - Provider A   - 5
Hospital A   - Provider B   - 30
Hospital A   - Provider C   - 5
Hospital B   - Provider A   - 10
Hospital B   - Provider D   - 50
Hospital C   - Provider E   - 12
etc...
```

I want to work out for each Hospital, the proportion of each Provider. E.g. for Hospital A, it would be:

```
Provider A - 0.125
Provider B - 0.75
Provider C - 0.125
```

This is based on a large data table I have in excel. I have tried a few CountIF formulas, but can't quite get there.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56652638/edit) to provide the formulas you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image]

The formula in cell D2 and copied down is:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2)/SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C)
```